# Offline passwords manager accessible by multiple users

Tags: windows, offline, password-manager, multi-user

Looking for an offline password manager that encrypts passwords where the encrypted database file can be shared with multiple users and loaded/opened by them via Windows login within the same intranet. A self-hosted web-based tool would be acceptable as well.

Tried KeePass, its free, its offline, its encrypted database file is sharable and load/openable via Windows login, but only single user.

Free is always nice.

Comment: So you need something where users can access a password database all at the same time?

Comment: Yes, say I can setup the password database, allowing only a list of logins within the same intranet to open it up. They can access the passwords anytime without me to grant them access anymore. Of course if needed, the manager allows me to add or exclude more logins without having to recreate the database.

Comment: you could try a portable install and load it from a shared folder. im currently not in a LAN, so i cant really try it out. ive tried running portable programs on shared folders over LAN a while back and they all run just fine. its just a matter of trust since anyone can edit portables freely

Comment: For that, maybe a database-driven tool would be more convenient (no locking issues, as the database would handle that part). Would you consider a self-hosted web-based tool, if there were one?

Comment: @Izzy Sure! Although my needs is just read rights for the multiple users, only I have edit rights, I dont mind to see some full fledged tools.

Answer (score 1):

KeePass does fine with multiple users:
http://keepass.info/help/base/multiuser.html - the 'Syncronize' option is what you want.
There's even an advanced option that automatically takes the 'syncronize' option when saving.

You just have to make sure that only people who need the database have access to the share and it should work fine (it does for me).

Comment: Thanks, I did try that and agree to what you said when multiple users sharing the same master key. One of my requirements are to allow multiple users to load/open the database with their only keys (e.g. Windows login), so that I don't have to manage the master key when managing the other passwords. Without an inbuild ACL, KeePass can only allow a single user to use Windows login as a mean to load/open the database.

Comment: @user1589188 - Ahh, that wasn't clear to me. Please note though, that doing that brings up some other issues, and you might want to insure that any solution you find includes logging - if many users have access, then when you drop a user, you'll want to change any password that user had access to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the Windows aspect (don't use that myself), but I've used [TeamPasswordManager](https://teampasswordmanager.com) both professionally and personally as a self-hosted web based password manager. It's cheap and the developer offers good support, is very responsive and open to feature requests.